# compression levels gz and xz

Tags: gzip, xz

Why isn't there any difference (output filesize) with these command lines?

## Gzip stdin

The output files have same filesize even though the compression levels are different

```
tar ... | gzip -c -1 > ...
tar ... | gzip -c -9 > ...
```

## xz stdin

The output files have same filesize even though the compression levels are different

```
tar ... | xz -c -1 > ...
tar ... | xz -c -9 > ...
```

## Gzip

The output files have same filesize even though the compression levels are different

```
GZ_OPT=-1 tar -zcf ...
GZ_OPT=-9 tar -zcf ...
```

## xz

The output files have same filesize even though the compression levels are different

```
XZ_OPT=-1 tar -Jcf ...
XZ_OPT=-9 tar -Jcf ...
```

Comment: They look quite different to me. Perhaps you can [edit] to explain what aspect you're interested in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gzip compression level does not *guarantee* that higher compression levels result in smaller output. In fact the BUGS section of my `man gzip` notes that in some cases it can be the opposite.

For xz (and bzip2), this is even more documented, as according to the manual the numerical level controls the amount of memory used by the compressor. Using more memory is supposed to make better compression, but again this is not guaranteed.

Especially if your test data is small, having the same size output is not surprising to me.